# Combining the "recovery" tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Here's a list of tags related to "recovery":

- [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) (493)
- [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) (464)
- [password-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) (63)
- [hard-drive-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive-recovery) (56)
- [file-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-recovery) (37)
- [system-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-recovery) (10)
- [partition-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition-recovery) (5, this was just added in the last 30 days)

Where do you see overlap? Which ones should be made synonyms of others?  I'd at least vote for merging [partition-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition-recovery) into [hard-drive-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive-recovery).

Comment: `[file-recovery]` => `[data-recovery]`

Comment: [system-recovery] => [recovery]

Comment: `[hard-drive-recovery]` sounds more like the click of death problem, whereas `[partition-recovery]` more like "I deleted my Windows partition when installing Linux"

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that [password-recovery] should be combined with [recovery], as we all know that good passwords are not stored in a recoverable manner, and it usually either:

1. Gets deleted and a new one gets made
2. User clicks Forgot password, deletes old password and makes a new one

I do agree with the others though

Comment: Since this site doesn't handle web applications, password recovery might be applicable for getting saved passwords back from web browsers, FTP clients, etc.

Comment: I don't like to admit when I'm wrong, but I can definitely see that coming up, and being within the scope of the sire. Answer retracted